# Parent process to monitore and fork new child processes depending on exit status

Tags: c, posix

I've created the below code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i, n, N;
        pid_t pid;
        int status;

        N = atoi(argv[1]);

        for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                pid = fork();
                if(pid==0) {
                        srand(getpid() * getppid());
                        n = rand() % 10 + 1;
                        printf("I'm child nº %d with childpid %d, parent pid = %d, n = %d\n", i, getpid(), getppid(), n);
                        exit(n);
                }
        }

        while ((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0))) {
                if (pid < 0)
                        ;
                else if (WEXITSTATUS(status) < 4)
                        printf("exit status %d lower than 4\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
        wait(NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

The idea is a parent process forking N child process and each of them exiting with a random value. I want my parent process to monitor all the child processes and fork a new child if the exit status is, for instance <4. This will be going on until all process exit with a status >= 4.

Comment: So just fork a new child if the last one returned status lower then 4.

Comment: But what happens if the new child return again another status lower than 4?

Comment: Then it's exit status is available with `waitpid` interface. So you check it's exit status, and fork again.

Comment: I'm already using waitpid, the issue here is that child processes can keep ending with status < 4, how can I make the parent process keep forking child processes indefinitely, if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Solved creating a function copying the code from parent and child (keeping the code in main() untouched). The parent calls the function, the function forks another process, and the parent in the same function calls the function recursively under the conditions we choose.